# Hyperlinks in gmail message

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email from php smtp.
A part of the message is `<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>`  and `href='http://www.google.com'> B </a>`

But I do not see hyperlinks in the received gmail message.
The email just looks as the above string.
How do I get hyperlinks?

The php code looks like:

```
$body = "Something including the above code";
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$headers = array( 'From' => $from, 'To' => $email, 'Subject' => $subject ); 
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(... host port uth username password ... )); 
$mail = $smtp->send($email, $headers, $body)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add headers to email message
example :

```
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html;';
$message = <<<EOD
    <h1> Hello World  <h1>
    <a href="https://search.yahoo.com/">goto Yahoo</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">goto Google</a>   
EOD;

$result = mail('your-email@gmail.com', 'hello world', $message,$headers);
if($result){
   echo 'message sent'; 
}else{
   echo 'failure';
}
```

you can read more about sending html with mail function at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)